# create a node with two attributes in Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have XML as given below:

```
<test>
<a>Hello</a>
</test>
```

I need to add a new node with two attributes in XQuery and the expected output is:

```
<test>
<a>Hello</a>
<b att1="1" att2="2">World</b>
</test>
```

Can you help me out with the XQquery for this?

Comment: What did you try? Please don't spam tags, [tag:xslt] is of no relevance for this question, so don't use it.

Comment: XQuery is just for querying data, if you want to modify data that is what _XQuery Update_ is for. What processor are you using, does it support XQuery Update? If not, there might be some implementation-specific update mechanism. Of course, you could also opt to recreate the whole element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XQuery Update and BaseX, following will be the solution -

```
let $i := <b att1="1" att2="2">World</b>
for $x in doc('document1')/test
   return insert node $i after $x/a
```

Here I have assumed that you have created a XML Doc in BaseX.